# Does "align on alignment marker" work in Mathematica 12.3

Tags: bugs, alignment, text-formatting, version-12.3

In Mathematica 12.1 (and previous versions), you can insert a cell of style `DisplayFormula` into a notebook, using `Format/Style/DisplayFormula` from the menu. You can then use `Format/Text Alignment/On AlignmentMarker` to set it to align lines of the `DisplayFormula` on alignment marks, which can be inserted by typing <esc>am<esc>. Other than that, such a cell acted like a left-aligned `Displayformula` cell. (There was, as far as I can find, no way to simultaneously set align on marker and left/right/center alignment.)

I just upgraded to 12.3, and this no longer works. If I insert a `DisplayFormula` and set it to align on markers, text in the cell disappears from the display. It has not been deleted--anything you type becomes visible again if you change the alignment to something else. In fact, if you type a lot into a marker-aligned `DisplayFormula`, for instance, by holding down the `x` key and letting autorepeat do its work, you can see that the contents of the cell seem to be centered somewhere off-window to the right. This is a purely cosmetic problem, but still very annoying.

Question: Has anyone else encountered this problem? Or figured out a way to solve it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As far as I know was Format/Text Alignment/On AlignmentMarker broken in 12.2 (Frontend crash). So something might have been fixed in 12.3 but probably not 100% correct. I would report the issue to WRI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I sent WRI a notebook illustrating the problem. They agreed it was a bug. Presumably it'll be fixed in a future version. Soon, I hope.

Version 12.3.1 was just released. It still has the bug.

I just upgraded to 13.0.0. Based on a quick check with some old notebooks, the bug appears to have been fixed.